# Unable to set StreamVolume index for ringer

Tags: android

I am using the following code-

***mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(2,50, 1);***

to set ringer volume to 50. The value remains unchanged.

Comment: can you please post the mAudioManager initialization?

Comment: @user1260028-private AudioManager mAudioManager;
mAudioManager= (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);